# Python - Splitting lists of integers during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of data where I'm taking a slice through a 3D array of floats and appending the numbers of the elements that satisfy a set of upper and lower bounds (also floats).

The first part of my code contains a nested `for` loop in the style of the following:

```
x_lst = []
for i in range(len(x1)):
    for x in range(len(floatarray[0,:,0])):
        if x1[i] <= floatarray[0,x,0] <= x2[i]:
            x_lst.append(x)
            #issues after this point
```

The inner loop compares the data in the array (`floatarray[0,x,0]`) with the boundaries `x1` and `x2`, returning a list of integers, whilst the outer loop iterates through the values of the boundaries.

The issue I have is that the output (`x_lst`) is a single list, whereas I've been trying to produce a list of lists, with each sublist corresponding to the iterable `i`.

e.g.

```
#Desired output
x_lst = [[5,6,7,13,14],[21,22,23,36,37],[44,45,...

#Actual output
x_lst = [5,6,7,13,14,21,22,23,36,37,44,45,...
```

I feel like there's a very simple way of doing this, but I've not been able come up with anything that works (such as trying to use `x_lst.split()` after the append).

Also, any feedback on the question would be great as I'm still fairly new to SO.

Comment: Are these supposed to be NumPy arrays? You're using list notation, but lists don't support the kind of indexing you're doing.

Comment: In this case `floatarray` is a NumPy array as I had to use several NumPy features to arrange the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so Sam's answer is correct insofar as appending the values through the iteration, but trying it out with my code produced lists of lists of `len(i)` where each sublist contained **all** values of `x` that satisfied all elements of `x1` and `x2`, instead of each list containing values specific to the `[i]`th element of `x1` and `x2`, thus all the sublists were identical.

I got around this by replacing the inner `for` loop with a list comprehension, as follows, that gave the right result (in the desired form `x_lst = [[5,6,7,13,14],[21,22,23,36,37],[44,45,...`):

```
x_lst = []

for i in range(len(x1)):
    y = [x for x in range(len(floatarray[0,:,0])) if x1[i] <= floatarray[0,x,0] <= x2[i]]
    x_lst.append(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the following should work: why not create an intermediate sublist for each `i`, and add appropriate values to the sublist, then finally add the sublist to the main list?

```
x_lst = []
for i in range(len(x1)):
    inner_list = []  # The sublist to be appended.
    for x in range(len(floatarray[0,:,0])):
        if x1[i] <= floatarray[0,x,0] <= x2[i]:
            inner_list.append(x)  # Add the numbers to the sublist.
            # Issues after this point...
    x_lst.append(inner_list)  # Add the sublist to the main list.
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something I was missing but I had a total mental block as to what it was.

Comment: When I checked through the results, I found that instead this way was producing nested lists of `len(i)` with each sublist containing all values of `x` that satisfy all the bounds, so I was getting `len(i)` identical lists. I think I can see why my original code would do this in the conditional statement, so I managed to get the desired result by replacing it with a list comprehension (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Everything appears to be correct in the code except that you append into a 1-d array. For solving your problem you can simply change your code so that a temporary array named temp will append data in inner loop which would then be appended to your outer array x_lst as shown below:

```
x_lst = []

for i in range(len(x1))

temp=[]
for x in range(len(floatarray[0,:,0])):

    if x1[i] <= floatarray[0,x,0] <= x2[i]:

         temp.append(x)

x_lst.append(temp);
```